# Authenticate Service Account for Remote Config REST API using Go

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-platform, firebase-remote-config, google-client

[Over here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest#step_2_get_an_access_token_to_authenticate_and_authorize_api_requests) the *Firebase docs* explain how you can retrieve a [***token***](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest#raw_http_request) required to make requests to the [Remote Config Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest).

It provides example code for *Python, Java and Node.js*. Because there is no code for **Go**, it *sends me* to the [Google Client Library (for Go)](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client). You might be able to understand why I am getting lost there...

The examples use [`GoogleCredential` *in Java*](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/blob/master/config/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/samples/config/Configure.java#L43), [`ServiceAccountCredentials` *in Python*](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-python/blob/master/config/configure.py#L20) and [`google.auth.JWT` in *Node.js*](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/blob/master/config/index.js#L18). I was not able to find any of those [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client). I do not know why there are no clear naming conventions.

#### I have found

[`firebaseremoteconfig-gen.go`](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/firebaseremoteconfig/v1/firebaseremoteconfig-gen.go): The code looks like it already implements what the *Firebase documentation page tries to achieve "manually"*. Comparison: [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest#step_3_get_json_from_the_service_with_the_api), [package](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/firebaseremoteconfig/v1/firebaseremoteconfig-gen.go#L345).

#### Help

Because the ["Usage example" of the package](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/firebaseremoteconfig/v1/firebaseremoteconfig-gen.go#L8) ends strangely abrupt and is the opposite of extensive, I do not understand how to make use of it.

I would be helped if someone could tell me how I can use this:

```
firebaseremoteconfigService, err := firebaseremoteconfig.New(oauthHttpClient)
```

I could not figure out where I would get `oauthHttpClient` from. There is an `oauth2` package in the repository, but there I face [the same problem](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/oauth2/v2/oauth2-gen.go#L9):

```
oauth2Service, err := oauth2.New(oauthHttpClient)
```

I need `oauthHttpClient` again, so this cannot be a solution.
[`http.Client`](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/firebaseremoteconfig/v1/firebaseremoteconfig-gen.go#L48) could be anything, but I need to authenticate with a `service-account.json` file, like [shown in the three example snippets here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest#step_2_get_an_access_token_to_authenticate_and_authorize_api_requests).

#### Tags explanation

I hope that someone has either had experience with integrating ***Firebase Remote* Config** with **Go**, someone knows how ***Google Client API** authentication* works or someone is good enough with **Go** to get how the usage works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of main ways of authenticating with the google APIs, they are documented here:

[Link to docs](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/4d8a15a217e46f47fb724569d74702bec99852d3/GettingStarted.md#oauth-http-client)

The ways documented are "3-legged OAuth", "Using API Keys" and finally "Service Accounts".

From the links that you've included in the question; you are looking at the Python / Java / Node examples of "Service Accounts".

**Using Service Accounts in go**

The `oauthHttpClient` that you are referring to, is an http client that will attach the authentication information to the requests automatically.

You can create one using this package:

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google

The examples linked in other languages use a "service account json key file".

Using the method linked below, you can read that keyfile and create a `jwt.Config` struct that will give you access to the client that you need.

https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2/google#JWTConfigFromJSON

The go equivalent of the other language examples linked is;

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/path/to/your-project-key.json")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.remoteconfig")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
// Initiate an http.Client. The following GET request will be
// authorized and authenticated on the behalf of
// your service account.
client := conf.Client(oauth2.NoContext)
client.Get("...")
```

Comment: I would have never extracted that from the docs :) This works nicely for my own `Get` requests. However, requests I execute through the [`firebaseremoteconfig-gen` package](https://github.com/google/google-api-go-client/blob/master/firebaseremoteconfig/v1/firebaseremoteconfig-gen.go#L404) fail and I was not able to fix their requests. I am sure that it fails because they are adding too much to the http request *(with `gensupport`)*. I do not want to bother with that anymore because I cannot seem to find a solution. I will just control the JSON myself, which works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

I just started using the same library (from an AppEngine Standard project). This is how I am creating the service client:

```
import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    fb "google.golang.org/api/firebaseremoteconfig/v1"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
)

const (
    // Name of our service account file
    saFileName = "my-firebase-sa.json"

    // OAuth scopes used for remote config API
    scopeRemoteConfig = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.remoteconfig"
)

func createFirebaseService(ctx context.Context) (*fb.Service, error) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(saFileName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conf, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(data, scopeRemoteConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return fb.New(conf.Client(ctx))
}
```

And I call it as such:

```
func fetchConfig(ctx context.Context) (*fb.RemoteConfig, error) {
    s, err := createFirebaseService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed to create firebase service: %v", err)
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Failed to initialize Firebase service")
    }

    projectID := "projects/" + appengine.AppID(ctx)

    cfg, err := s.Projects.GetRemoteConfig(projectID).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Failed to call Firebase remote config API: %v", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return cfg, nil
}
```

The code is using the Project ID to form its path; after reading through the lib code I noticed it was missing /projects/ from that path; so I just prepended that to my project ID and it works ;-) At least until they fix that and my code stops working..

Hopefully this helps someone.